# Tools not working on Garry's Mod multiplayer

Tags: garrys-mod

I'm playing Garrys Mod, Multiplayer on LAN and for whatever reason, tools aren't working. I can't find any setting to turn them on, either. And, when I say "not working," I mean that their groups are showing up in the spawn menu, but there is nothing to select.

Comment: Do the default "tools" and weapons show up?  If they do can you use them properly?

Comment: @ursa_arcadius: The default weapons work. But there are no tools to select/use.

Comment: Can you use the physics gun as one of the default weapons? Also, are there any settings that would disable using any tools in multiplayer? I could see there being an option if you wanted to keep people from griefing on your server (although doing so would make little sense in LAN).

Comment: @SadlyNot: Yes, the physics gun is one of the default weapons and I can use it. I don't know of any setting to turn off tools.

Comment: I would guess that the server has certain tools disabled.

Comment: Would this have anything to do with permissions?

Comment: By 'groups' do you mean the labels such as 'Construction' show up, but there are no tools (i.e, Thruster, Balloon, Muscle) in those categories?

Answer (score 1):

You're probably missing a some Lua files,  to fix this I suggest one of a few things.

1. Use Steam to verify the install by right clicking the game and going to **Properties** -> **Local Files** -> **Validate Integrity Of Game Files**

   - Or if you're running a server: `steamcmd.exe +login anonymous +app_update 4020 validate +quit`
2. Run the `FactoryReset-GMod.bat` file in the root GarrysMod folder
3. Manually verify / download the files from the [Garry's Mod Github](https://github.com/Facepunch/garrysmod/tree/master/garrysmod/lua) and replace old ones. (**I Advice against this** as the files are development level and may not be fully tested.)